# React trying to define props dynamically, missing semicolon error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm using apexcharts for creating a chart. I need to define my chart items in props and I'm trying to use a props like this : series = {[{}]}.

series is an array, and each series element is an object. I'm trying to create this array elements dynamically.

[image: series props]

cevaplarDistinct and answers array are working correctly but I guess I have an syntax error. I'm react newbie and maybe my jsx syntax is can be wrong.

Can you help me about this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, inside your if condition you are creating an object but aren't assigning it to any variable. It should be assigned to some variable like

```
const obj = { name: el.textCevap,data:[5]}
```